# Symfony - how to autowire abstract class in services.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have 4 classes which extend an abstract class. I also have event listener in which I use that abstract class because I implemented chain of responsibility design pattern. Now I have a problem because I don't know how to define abstract class in services.yaml file.

```
  Services\AbstractClass:
  abstract: true
  autowire: true
  arguments:
        - '@Services\AbstractClass'
Services\Service1: 
  parent: Services\AbstractClass
  arguments: - '@Services\AbstractClass'
EventListener\MyEventListener:
  arguments:
    - '@annotations.cached_reader'
    - '@Services\AbstractClass'
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

When I try this I get an error: `The definition "EventListener\MyEventListener" has a reference to an abstract definition "Services\AbstractClass". Abstract definitions cannot be the target of references.`

Comment: It's because you can't instantiate an abstract class. And that's what you are you are trying to do in your event listener constructor. You could instantiate another class that extends this abstract class

Comment: When I add class which extends abstract class like this:     Services\Service1:
      parent: Services\AbstractClass
      arguments:
        - '@Services\AbstractClass' , I get an error: Attribute autowire  cannot be inherited from "_defaults" when a "parent" is set.  Move your child definitions to a separate file or define this attribute explicitly.

Comment: I updated question. I also added autowire:true and I get the same erro

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my answer... you should add `autowire:true` in the definition of the childrens. I gonna write a real detailled answer

Comment: Still the same  error

Comment: check the real answer

Comment: I think you are on the wrong track completely.  Think about it.  If you have four child classes deriving from your abstract base class then which class should the container inject into your event listener?  Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to use an interface or possibly a service locator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class so set an abstract class in any argument has no sense. And has you are configuring services with parents, the children should have `autowire: true` and `autoconfigure: false` in order to work proprely. Your service.yaml should look something like this

```
Services\AbstractClass:
  abstract: true

Services\Service1: 
  parent: Services\AbstractClass
  autowire: true
  autoconfigure: false

EventListener\MyEventListener:
  arguments:
    - '@annotations.cached_reader'
    - '@Services\Service1'
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Comment: What about other 3 services that implement abstract class, should I add them all as arguments in MyEventLIstener

Comment: Well, i don't know what your MyEventListener need... I just showed you how you can correctly configure an abstract class and it's children without errors in the service.yaml...

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns the same error

Comment: ok so i need more context... Can you update your question with your whole service.yaml config, add your abstract class and your services that extends this abstract class  ?